# Конфликт в трактовании смысла нормы права

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, семантика

**Есть следующая норма**: юридическое или физическое лицо, в том числе индивидуальный предприниматель, не являющееся участником, вправе подать жалобу в уполномоченный орган по государственным закупкам **только** до истечения срока для подготовки и подачи предложений в части, касающейся приглашения или документов, представляемых участнику для подготовки предложения.

**Моё трактование:** Лицо, не являющееся участником, вправе подать жалобу в части, касающейся приглашения или документов, представляемых участнику для подготовки предложения, **только до истечения срока для подготовки и подачи предложения**. (Т.е. имеется ввиду в этой части можно подать жалобу только до этого срока, а в других частях в соотв. с остальными нормами).

**Трактование должностного лица:** Лицо, не являющееся участником, вправе подать жалобу **только до истечения срока** для подготовки и подачи предложений **и только в части**, касающейся приглашения или документов, представляемых участнику для подготовки предложения. (Т.е. имеется ввиду, что такое лицо может подать жалобу только в этой части, по другим поводам жалобу такое лицо подать не может).

**Кто прав? Если я, то как грамотно доказать?**

Answer (score 1):

Ключевые слова: "**предложения в части** (того-то)" - эти слова *не разделяются* какой-либо пунктуацией и потому выглядят как основа общего понятия. Речь идёт о существовании ограничительного срока для "подачи предложений в части, касающейся...[**участников**]". В порядке такого (= в той же части) *предложения* "**неучастником**" может быть подана *жалоба*, но только пределах того же срока. Иных прав "*неучастника*" здесь не оговорено, но нельзя исключить их существование в других пунктах или документах.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Если я правильно понимаю, вы имеете ввиду, что данной нормой установлено право для неучастников на подачу жалобы в части, указанной в статье. При этом установлено ограничение по сроку на подачу такой жалобы. При этом никаких других ограничений и запретов данной нормой не установлено. Поэтому, если в других нормах не сказано иное, неучастник имеет право подать жалобу и по другим частям закупки, т.к. данная статья это не запрещает. Alex_ander, я правильно понял?

Comment: Я бы сказал, что для "неучастников" эта норма сформулирована как исключение. Хотя других ограничений, кроме сроков по конкретному виду обращений, нет, других прав для них (обращения неучастников по другому поводу и т. п.) отсюда не следует - их нужно искать отдельно.